# How to add odoo live chat javascripts in website theme layout?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, livechat

How to add odoo live chat javascripts in website theme layout?

I want to add the following in my odoo website page, in the documentation instruction :

Copy and paste this code into your website, within the tag:
But the problem is its not working when i paste it there. I am thinking maybe there is a proper way to do it.

```
<link href="http://localhost:8069/web/css/im_livechat.external_lib" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://localhost:8069/web/js/im_livechat.external_lib" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8069/im_livechat/loader/mydb/4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the **website.layout** template and paste your script codes inside the **head** tag. Hope that will works and while loading the homepage You can see the chat wizard.

Answer (score -1):

Put your`*.js files under /your_module/static/src/js and *.css /static/src/css` .

And, add that files in your template

```
<template id="id">
   <link href="/you_module/static/src/css/your_css.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="/web/static/src/css/your_css.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</template>
```

Hope it will help you.